# Want to run elasticsearch with Laravel app in docker, but it doesn't work

Tags: docker

I have laravel app that lives in docker, and I want to integrate elasticsearch to my app
That is how my docker-compose.yaml looks

```
version: '3'
services:
  laravel:
    build: ./docker/build
    container_name: laravel
    restart: unless-stopped
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - 8084:80
      - "22:22"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/settings:/settings
      - ../2agsapp:/var/www/html
      # - vendor:/var/www/html/vendor
      - ./docker/temp:/backup
      - composer_cache:/root/.composer/cache
    environment:
      - ENABLE_XDEBUG=true
    links:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.2
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./docker/db_config:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "8989:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=dev
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=dev
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=laravel
    command: --innodb_use_native_aio=0
  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: pma_laravel
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=dev
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=dev
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=laravel
      - PMA_HOST=mysql
    ports:
      - 8083:80
    links:
      - mysql
  es:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.1
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node

volumes:
  storage:
  composer_cache:
```

I run `docker-compose up -d` and then got really strange issue
If I execute `curl localhost:9200` inside laravel container it returns this message `Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused` 
But if I wull run `curl localhost:9200` out of the docker it returns expected response

Maybe I don't understand how it works, hope someone will help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you want to access another container within some container you should use the container name, not `localhost`.

If you are inside `laravel` and want to access Elasticsearch you should:

```
curl es:9200
```

Since you mapped the 9200 port to localhost (`ports` section in docker-compose) this port is available from your local machine as well, that's why curling from local machine to 9200 works.

Comment: @VitalyLinevich if it solves your question please accept my answer, otherwise let me know whats the error and I'll try to assist :)